# Changing input on the fly

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I want to ask about changing input on the fly in ffmpeg cli.

I have a few inputs like:

- png files
- two RTSP streams

and I want to change between those RTSP streams in fly because I'm streaming from IP cameras to youtube and I can not kill ffmpeg and run new one because this cause few seconds loss of video and audio.

So is there a way to change RTSP stream or other inputs in fly?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Please take the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to get your first badge

Comment: Ffmpeg does not have that feature.

Comment: Have you found a solution?